# Proof that $int(A)=\mathbb{C}-\overline{A^c}$

Tags: general-topology

I want to prove that $int(A)=\mathbb{C}-\overline{A^c}$, I know that this is equivalent to prove that

$$Int(A)=\overline{A^c}^c$$

So let's try to prove the first inclusion.

let $x \in int(A)$, as $int(A) \subseteq A \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ then naturally $x \in \mathbb{C}$, and there exists $r >0$ s.t.

$$B_{r}(x) \subseteq A$$
so then $B_{r}(x) \cap A ^c = \emptyset$.
Finally $x \in  \mathbb{C}-\overline{A^c}$.

The first inclusion seems clear, but the second inclusion is not so clear because I cannot guarantee that for some $\varepsilon >0$ $B_{\varepsilon}(x) \subseteq A$

Any suggestions on how to complete the exercise, I appreciate it!

Comment: What is the "second implication"? You mean "inclusion"?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin That's right, I confused the terminology

Comment: What is your definition of $\overline{X}$ for a subset $X$ of $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I say that $p \in \overline{X}$ if for any $r >0$ we have that $B(p, r) \cap X \neq \emptyset$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x\in\mathbb{C}\setminus \overline{A^c}$, then $x\notin \overline{A^{c}}$. Therefore, there exists $r\gt 0$ such that $B_r(x)\cap A^c=\varnothing$ (since $\overline{X}=\{x\mid \text{ for all }r\gt 0, B_r(x)\cap X\neq\varnothing\}$).

Therefore, $B_r(x)\subseteq (A^c)^c = A$, as desired.

---

This of course works in any topological space. If $x\in X\setminus\overline{A^c}$, then $x\notin\overline{A^c}$, so there exists an open set $U$ such that $x\in U$ and $U\cap A^c=\varnothing$. Since $U\cap A^c=\varnothing$, then $U\subseteq (A^c)^c = A$, so $x\in U\subseteq A$, showing that $x\in\mathrm{int}(A)$. Conversely, if $x\in \mathrm{int}(A)$, then there exists an open set $V$ such that $x\in V\subseteq A$, and therefore $V\cap A^c=\varnothing$, showing that $x\notin\overline{A^c}$.

Comment: How do you assure that $B_r(x)\subseteq (A^c)^c = A$, I don't see it at all clear

Comment: @Wrloord $B_r(x)\cap A^c=\varnothing$, so every thing in $B_r(x)$ is **not** in $A^c$, and therefore is in the complement of $A^c$.

Comment: I thought of something that reinforces what you say, as $\varepsilon>0$ is as small as you want, hence we can guarantee such containment. Can this be a true fact?

Comment: @Wrloord I do not understand your comment, or for that matter your problem. If a set $B$ does not intersect $C$, then it is contained in the complement of $C$. That is the only thing being used. It doesn't matter whether you can pick a small radius or a large radius. You know a ball with the given property exists **by definition** of closure of a set, and you are done.

Comment: I see, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The great thing about $\mathbb C$ is that you can draw. Even if such a drawing does not replace a demonstration, it is perhaps worth remembering that for many elementary topology results, the use of our intuition in the plan, for example, will remain a fairly reliable and in any case necessary guide.
[image]
$\forall x \in \mathbb C,$ $$x\in A^°\iff \exists r>0, \color{DarkGreen}{B_r(x)}\subset A $$$$\iff \exists r>0,\begin{array}{lcl}
 & \color{DarkGreen}{B_r(x)}\cap A^c=\emptyset & \overset{def}\iff & x \notin \overline {A^c } & 
\end{array}   \iff x \in \overline {A^c}^c$$